# The correct way to implement hreflang in magento sites

Tags: magento, seo

we have a website in Magento with four different stores PT, BR, EN, ES
we want HREFlang as:

pt-PT - Portuguese only for Portugal country

pt-BR - Portuguese only for Brazil country

EN - for all the English states

es-ES - Spanish only for the Spain.

I need to know the best and correct way to show hreflang on our different stores that will show zero error on google console!!

Comment: Why would a Magento site need something special here? Can’t you use the same way you’d use for any other site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?